# Very low cross-val score for regression with big .corr() between feature and result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Im trying to make regression with sklearn between one feature and one result.
This is the dataset that I have:

```
       bruto  ukupno gradjevinski din
0    2494.98                857951.27
1    2912.60                694473.11
2    3397.50               1310529.72
3    2678.00                199688.14
4    4310.00               1377366.95
5    2086.28                569312.33
6    3061.80                660803.42
7    4095.00               1187732.61
8    3997.00               1304793.08
9    6503.88               1659629.13
10   6732.00               1264178.31
11    940.10                172497.94
12   1543.00                598772.40
13   5903.85                809681.19
14   2861.61                333983.85
15   3682.76               1430771.50
16   2802.00               1145812.21
17   3032.00                356840.54
18   2635.00                543912.80
19   3749.00               1004940.27
20   4300.50               1889560.55
21   9722.00               2137376.95
22   3823.33                891633.50
23   1648.21                335115.40
24  24575.00              19273129.14
25   3926.00               1223803.28
26   3228.00                874000.00
27   4062.00               1090000.00
28   1316.24                332718.54
29   2497.99                519398.70
30  12123.94               2504783.69
31   2057.50                957042.37
32   2495.00                857951.27
33   3770.73               1743978.85
34    864.00                251269.48
35    774.71                192487.26
```

I have found the correlation between feature and result with .corr():

```
                            bruto  ukupno gradjevinski din
bruto                    1.000000                 0.878914
ukupno gradjevinski din  0.878914                 1.000000
```

I have corr of 0.87 and I think that that is very decent for regression, but when I make regression model and when i get cross-val score, i get value for cross-val score thats negative and bigger then 1 (sometimes -50.23) and thats very strange to me. I have tried with a lot of different models and with different number of folds but the results are the same. This is the code for regression:

```
features = df[['bruto']]
results = df[['ukupno gradjevinski din']]

regressors = [["Linear Regression", LinearRegression(normalize=False)],
              ["Lasso Regression", Lasso(normalize=False)],
              ["Gaussian Process Regressor", GaussianProcessRegressor()],              
              ["SVR linear", SVR(kernel = 'linear', gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR poly 2", SVR(kernel = 'poly', degree=2, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR poly 3", SVR(kernel = 'poly', degree=3, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR poly 4", SVR(kernel = 'poly', degree=4, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR poly 5", SVR(kernel = 'poly', degree=5, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR rbf C=0.01", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=0.01, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],              
              ["SVR rbf C=0.1", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=0.1, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR rbf C=0.5", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=0.5, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR rbf C=1", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=1, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],              
              ["SVR rbf C=10", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=10.0, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR rbf C=20", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=20.0, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["SVR rbf C=50", SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=50.0, gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],              
              ["SVR sigmoid", SVR(kernel = 'sigmoid', gamma='scale', max_iter = 1500)],
              ["GradientBoostingRegressor", GradientBoostingRegressor()],
              ["RandomForestRegressor", RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 150)],
              ["DecisionTreeRegressor", DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=10)],
              ["Bagging Regressor TREE", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=15))],
              ["Bagging Regressor FOREST", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100))],
              ["Bagging Regressor linear", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = LinearRegression(normalize=True))],
              ["Bagging Regressor lasso", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = Lasso(normalize=True))],
              ["Bagging Regressor SVR rbf", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=10.0, gamma='scale'))],
              ["Extra Trees Regressor", ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators = 150)],
              ["K-Neighbors Regressor 1", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)],
              ["K-Neighbors Regressor 2", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)],
              ["K-Neighbors Regressor 3", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3)],
              ["AdaBoostRegressor", AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=None)],
              ["AdaBoostRegressor tree", AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=15))],
              ["AdaBoostRegressor forest", AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100))],
              ["AdaBoostRegressor lin reg", AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression(normalize=True))],
              ["AdaBoostRegressor lasso", AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator = Lasso(normalize=True))]]


for reg in regressors:

     try:

           scores = cross_val_score(reg[1], features, results, cv=5)
           scores = np.average(scores)
           print('cross val score', scores)
           print()

     except:
          continue
```

I have tried to scale my features with Normalizer, StandardScaler and MinMaxScaler but results are the same.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post my answer on the other forum, but it's migrated to here.

There are a few crucial things that you should keep in mind:

1. > It’s not who has the best algorithm that wins. It’s who has the most data. (Banko and Brill, 2001)

Bank and Brill in 2001 made a comparison among 4 different algorithms, they kept increasing the Training Set Size to millions and came up with the above-quoted conclusion. **And your data is too few**!

2. Whenever you talk about Linear Models, just remember their enemy -- **The Outliers**. If you plot your data, you can see that clearly.

[image]

3. `cross_val_score` returns the R^2 by default for almost any Linear Model (i.e Regressor). The best value of this metric = 1 (i.e. totally fit), or = 0 (i.e. horizontal line), or it can be negative (i.e. worse than a horizontal line). [More info here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative). Next in the experiment I conducted, you'll see how the results are valid.
4. An alternative model would be the `Multi-layer Perceptron Regressor`; with number of layers = 3, the model would map any complicated function.
5. Cross-Validation would best serve if you have enough data. However in your case, the CV scores vary noticeably.

Please ponder the results of the following self-explanatory Experiment:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([2494.98,2912.6,3397.5,2678,4310,2086.28,3061.8,4095,3997,
              6503.88,6732,940.1,1543,5903.85,2861.61,3682.76,2802,3032,
              2635,3749,4300.5,9722,3823.33,1648.21,24575,3926,3228,4062,1316.24,
              2497.99,12123.94,2057.5,2495,3770.73,864,774.71]).reshape(-1, 1)

y = np.array([857951.27,694473.11,1310529.72,199688.14,1377366.95,569312.33,660803.42,1187732.61,
          1304793.08,1659629.13,1264178.31,172497.94,598772.4,809681.19,333983.85,1430771.5,1145812.21,
          356840.54,543912.8,1004940.27,1889560.55,2137376.95,891633.5,335115.4,19273129.14,1223803.28,
          874000,1090000,332718.54,519398.7,2504783.69,957042.37,857951.27,1743978.85,251269.48,192487.26])

X_, y_ = zip(*sorted(zip(X, y)))
plt.plot(X_, y_, '-x')
plt.title("Plot of Dataset")
plt.show()

print("Linear Regression :: Before Removing An Outlier")
reg = LinearRegression()
print(np.average(cross_val_score(reg, X, y, cv=3)))

X, y = X_[:-1], y_[:-1]
plt.plot(X, y, '-x')
plt.title("Plot of Dataset After Removing Outlier")
plt.show()

print("Linear Regression :: After Removing An Outlier")
reg = LinearRegression()
print(np.average(cross_val_score(reg, np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1), y, cv=3)))

print("Multi-layer Perceptron Regressor :: The Effect of Mapping Complicated / Non-Linear Function")
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(16, 16, 16), random_state=2020, activation='identity', max_iter=1000)
print(np.average(cross_val_score(mlp, np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1), y, cv=3)))
```

---

### RESULTS

This after removing only one extreme value (*without further exploration nor doing any fancy work like utilizing any [outliers detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354094/pythonic-way-of-detecting-outliers-in-one-dimensional-observation-data)*). As you can see, there would be no single line that fits all points.

[image]

```
Linear Regression :: Before Removing An Outlier
Average CVs Score: -1.7085612243433703

Linear Regression :: After Removing An Outlier
Average CVs Score: -0.12386365189238795

Multi-layer Perceptron Regressor :: The Effect of Mapping Complicated / Non-Linear Function
Average CVs Score: 0.16131374234257037
```